# How to not escape backslash when writing to JSON

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, escaping

I am trying to read a JSON file and add a new `key,value` pair to it. Then write the JSON file back. Example

```
# Read the JSON and add a new K,V
input_file_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'test.json')
input_file = open(input_file_path, 'r')
data = json.load(input_file)
data['key'] = os.environ.get('KEY', '') #<-- Adding a new K,V
input_file.close()

# Write the JSON to tmp.
output_file = open('/tmp/' + 'test.json', 'w')
json.dump(data, output_file, indent=4)
output_file.close()
```

My input JSON looks like this

```
{
  "type": "account"
}
```

My env variable called `KEY` looks like this
`-----BEGINKEY-----\nVgIBMIIE`

The final JSON file written to tmp looks like this

```
{
  "private_key": "-----BEGINKEY-----\\nVgIBMIIE",
  "type": "account"
}
```

I am not able to figure out why the backslash is escaped? How can I avoid this?

Comment: Is that \tmp\ a typo while you were writing the question?

Comment: No I am writing to `/tmp`. That part of the logic works fine. When I open the file `\n` in the value is escaped.

Comment: You mean /tmp ... \tmp is tab + mp

Comment: Ah yea `/tmp` error while I was copy pasting the code here. Wanted to just paste the relevant part.

Comment: Have you tried with `ensure_ascii=False` argument to json.dump?

Comment: Yes I have. It didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The program is treating your input string as a raw string and so adds the extra `\`. The original '\' is not actually escaping anything, so for it to be represented in Python as a string, you need to escape it. As you saw this can be problematic however. You can force the string back to unicode format using:

```
import codecs

raw_val = os.environ.get('KEY', '')
val = codecs.decode(raw_val, 'unicode_escape')
data['key'] = val
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to represent `-----BEGINKEY-----\nVgIBMIIE` in JSON, it has to go in a double quoted string.

In double quoted strings, backslashes have special meaning. It's not possible to write a backslash character simply by typing `"\"`. This would generate an error.

Therefore, the backslash must be escaped. Hence `-----BEGINKEY-----\nVgIBMIIE` becomes `"-----BEGINKEY-----\\nVgIBMIIE"` in a JSON string.

If you want to get rid of the backslash, you need to represent

```
-----BEGINKEY-----
VgIBMIIE
```

rather than

```
-----BEGINKEY-----\nVgIBMIIE
```

These two things are not the same thing.

Comment: He's reading json file and, I guess, wants to save it back as is.

Comment: They value that is stored in the env variable called KEY is of the form `-----BEGINKEY-----\nVgIBMIIE`. It is a huge string which is a private key. I am adding the private key into the JSON. I don't have control over how its formatted and I can't have it as line separated.